# Overwriting AbstractClass fields with mypy and Django

Tags: python, django, mypy

In our project we subclass the `AbstractUser` model from Django:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name_prefix = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    registered_on = models.DateTimeField(default=now, editable=False)
    organizations = models.ManyToManyField(
        "Organization", through="UserOrganization"
    )

    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS: List[str] = []

    def __str__(self):
        if not self.last_name_prefix:
            return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}"
        return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name_prefix} {self.last_name}"
```

We want to remove the username field and as specified in the Django docs you do this by setting the field to `None`. However, we also use mypy, and it complains that the None type is not compatible with the values it expects for a charfield:

```
error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "None", base class "AbstractUser" defined the type as "CharField[Union[str, int, Combinable], str]")
```

I also tried removing the field with `delattr` which worked, but wasn't picked up by Django migrations. I know it's possible to use '# type: ignore' but is there any proper way to fix this (other than rewriting the AbstractUser class and removing it there)?

Comment: Simply remove `username = None`, this is a suggestion for older Django versions.

Comment: @hoefling but this would keep the username column in the database, we don't want that. Also the `= None` is mentioned in the latest documentation (3.1) https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/#field-name-hiding-is-not-permitted

Answer (score -1):

Try replacing this `username = None` to

```
username = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=None)
```

By this, if you don't pass any value to `username` then it will be `None`.

You can also remove `username` field if you are not using it.

Comment: This would still keep the column in the database

Comment: Then, You can also remove the `username` field if you are not using it.

Comment: If by removing you mean leaving out the `username = ...`, that won't work. The username  field is defined in the `AbstractUser` class, which means `User` class will inherit it by default. And like I said, `= None` gives a mypy error

Comment: This solution is kinda weird from the database point of view - it will keep an empty column in the table